# textFieldの青い棒を消したい

Tags: swift, ios

textFieldをタップしてキーボード部分にpickerを表示するという実装をしようとしています。
タップしたときにtextFieldに青い棒が出てくるのを非表示にしたいです。
青い棒の名称も教えて欲しいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キャレット(カレット)もしくは単にカーソルという人が多いと思います。

こちら[本家のStack Overflowの回答で一番簡単なの](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101376/6541007)を引っ張り出すと、iOS 7以降であればこれで良いようです。

```
textField.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

(キャレットを消すと言う効果があることはどこにも明示されておらず)『「今は動く」型の実装であり、お勧めできない』と言うコメントもありますので、そのようなやり方が気にくわない場合は、[`UITextField`をサブクラス化して`caretRectForPosition(_:)`をオーバライドしてやると言う回答の方](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13660503/6541007)を使われると良いでしょう。